# Java difference in size when serializing to disk and sending across network

Tags: java, networking, serialization

I am trying to measure the amount of bandwidth used by my program to send Java objects across the network. I thought I could simply serialise the objects to disk and use the file size as an indication, but this seems to not be the case. What I did was serialise the objects to a file while capturing the network usage with tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump -l -i lo port 54544 | tee test_112_512
```

Then to determine the total traffic used I used the following command:

```
cat test_112_512 | grep '54544 >' | awk '{N = N + $NF + 20} END {print N}'
```

The 20 bytes is to account for the TCP headers (~250 packets) which tcpdump does not account for when reporting the length. The grep part is to ignore any traffic coming back since I am not interested in that.

Using this method I find that the total network traffic is up to 10% less than the file size on disk. And since the file on disk has no TCP headers  this is an unexpected result. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28data_storage%29

Comment: You should post this as an answer, rather than comment.

Comment: I'm using `ls -l` to get the file size, so it might be that

Answer (score 0):

Java Serialization is always the same size regardless of destination.  One thing which can reduce the amount sent is what you sent before on the same stream. e.g. if you write an object to an existing stream it is likely to be smaller than if you were to write it to a file alone.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you haven't accounted for all the TCP overheads. For example, TCP headers can be longer that 20 bytes, they are variable length, and maybe you haven't accounted for the connect and close handshakes, ACKs etc either.